# App with Construct 2 and CocoonJS is not running on apple

Tags: ios, iphone, construct-2, cocoonjs

i recently programmed an app with construct 2 and exported it with cocoonJS.
The app runs smoothly on every android device I testes (Nexus 5, Samsung Galaxy S3) but not on apple. I was testing it with an Ipad 2 and Iphone 4s but it always crashes.

The strange thing: When I remove some pictures from the app, it starts working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of a memory usage. You need to be careful while using images. One image of 1024x1024 takes like 4MB in bitmaps memory usage, so application would be crashing if you have lots of images.